# Is the :key attribute mandatory in v-for loops?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, v-for

i don't have a real problem, just i read somewhere once that a :key attribute in vue 3 is not mandatory in a v-for loop.
Is this correct and if so, when do I need a key in v-for loops and when not?
Or do I not need it at all ?
What is it needed for if it is necessary?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It's better for you to use it in all v-for loops.

> [The key special attribute is used as a hint for Vue's virtual DOM
> algorithm to keep track of a node's identity. That way, Vue knows when
> it can reuse and patch existing nodes and when it needs to reorder or
> recreate them.](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/key-attribute.html)